# What are the pros and cons using javascript in our form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I got this code in my submit form

> ```
> <form id="myform" action='hello.php' method='GET'>
>     <input type="button" name="newWin" onclick="frmSubmitSameWindows();">
>     <input type="button" name="SameWin" onclick="frmSubmitNewWindows();">
> <form>
> ```

Then use some js functions in the head;

```
function frmSubmitSameWindows() {
form.target = '';
form.submit();
}


function frmSubmitNewWindows() {
form.target = '_blank';
form.submit();
}
```

What is the pro and cons when we use javascript event function such as frmSubmitSameWin() and frmSubmitNewWin() in our form ? as far as i concern, this is the best solution when **we need a way to submit things**. Is there other preference ? the better way then the way i got now ?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but how come your form submits using GET instead of POST?

Comment: @R0MANARMY what the problem? it's becomes a get parameter.

Comment: The usual problem with that is that it makes it really easy for the same form submission to occur repeatedly, or for the result of the form submission to be cached by the web browser even if the result should change later. Also, it pollutes a user's browser with long ugly URLs that contain form data. It's not purely bad--just comes with a lot of ugly side-effects. There's a reason that POST is customary for form submission...

Comment: post is really recommend for forms that *edit* data, but maybe the SO wants to get data? one example is search form.

Comment: I've removed php tags as your question has nothing server side related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What are the pros and cons using javascript in <strike>our</strike> form?*

Pro: Offers seas of possibilities to improve user experience (dynamics, faster, no flash of content, etc).
Con: You should code it [unobtrusively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Your example is not. It fails when the client has JS disabled.

I've developed lots of websites since ages, but I can't seem to remember a valid business reason to have two submit buttons, one to submit the form in the same window and other to submit it into a new window. I'd suggest to rethink this approach and end up with one submit button. The other flaws in the code are already mentioned by Mendy.

Comment: maybe this is another WTF question ;D but is there any way to make it not fails when the client has JS disabled ? what i have to code to make it better ?

Comment: Either just use one button, or use two forms. The last is not really user friendly if you have to duplicate input fields as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use `onsubmit` event on the `form` element. and use `submit` inputs `instead` buttons. this way you can have a single function to determine what you wanna do.

In addition form target = 'blank' is not recommend, as it's deprecated, and it's not supported in HTML 4.01 Strict / XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD.